# What would be causing my Sitecore item's content (fields) not content tree, to be duplicated?

Tags: content-editor

We just installed 10.1, and I am working with a local instance of my Sitecore 10.1.
I pointed my connectionstrings to my DEV database and I rebuilt my indexes in Solr. When I opened up my content tree and click on an item, all of the fields are duplicated? there is an editable field and an identical un-editable field. see below. I checked my WEB database and this is also the case, very strange. what do I need to look at to troubleshoot? Note: I reverted my connectionstrings back to local and now I have a brand new instance of Sitecore (not my site) and no duplication. Also, my DEV environment does not have this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You entered into "Translate" mode:

[image]

Just click on "VERSIONS" ribbon and uncheck "translate" button.

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much!! I didn't even realize this. I was worried that I messed something up, as we upgraded from 8.2 to 10.1